# Socket.io 1.x clustering without sticky session?

Tags: websocket, socket.io-1.0

Is there any way to cluster Socket.io without these sticky session, with Redis?

Answer (score 0):

So after learning about other realtime modules, I finally used [Primus](https://github.com/primus/primus) that allow me to use any realtime engine seamlessly.

They do not provide a built-in way of clustering realtime engines, but I ended building a separated application that is dedicated to handle realtime connections. It can handles up to 1000 concurrent realtime users without any problems